# the meaning of "truffling grunts"

Tags: word-meaning

> The Tower is like a small town and its morning routine clatters on
>   around him, the guards and the men from the Mint greet him, and the
>   keeper of the king's beasts trots up to say it's dinner time – they
>   eat early, the beasts – and does he want to see them fed? I take it
>   very kindly, he says, waiving the pleasure; unbreakfasted himself,
>   slightly nauseous, he can smell stale blood and from the direction of
>   their cages hear their **truffling grunts** and smothered roars.
>
> — Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel

I looked up a few dictionaries but couldn't figure out what the "**truffling**" means here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Understanding this phrase requires some additional knowledge - specifically the existence of the edible fungal delicacy known as a [Truffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truffle) and the  method of acquiring said fungus most well-known in popular culture: sending out [trained pigs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truffle_hog), a practice known as 'truffling'.

With that information, it is readily apparent that 'truffling grunts' are simply the sort of noises you'd expect to hear from a pig with its snout in the ground searching for truffles.

As the animals are being fed in the snippet you provided, their snouts are indeed likely to be be in a similar position to the [truffling pig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truffle#/media/File:Cochon_truffier.JPG) (just with food instead of dirt), and so make similar noises.